# I with my friends vs my friends and I

Tags: subjects

I'm pretty sure it's not correct to say **I with my friends go to the cinema every weekend**. However I sometimes hear it from other Russians.

I have to use "and" instead of "with" and put this like this **My friends and I go to the cinema every weekend**. I'm still wondering what if...

Am I right or wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I would probably say either "I go to the cinema with my friends every weekend" or "I go to the cinema every weekend with my friends."

Answer (score 1):

The first form is correct, but only if the "with my friends" is in parenthesis:

> I (with my friends) go to the cinema every weekend.

However, this would only be used to stress the fact that you go to the cinema with your friends (for example if this had previously been put into doubt) and I really can only think of a couple of very specific contexts where it would be preferable to use this construction over an alternative.

To more generally state that you and your friends go to the cinema (particularly if your going to the cinema is more important than who you go with, or if your going to the cinema and your going there with friends are equally important) then the second form you proposed would be the correct one to use.

Please note I speak British English, and while I am fairly confident that what I've said also applies to other dialects, I am not certain of it.

Comment: It's not the use of the phrase, but its positioning, that's unidiomatic.  _I go to the cinema with my friends every weekend_ is quite normal.